# Google map LatLngBounds offset

Tags: android, google-maps

I have this code

```
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        builder.include(mainLocation);
        builder.include(userLocation);
        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 0);
        mMap.animateCamera(cu);
```

And this works it shows bounds but i would like to show bounds on the top half of the screen (is there a way to put offset y?).

[image]

(Hope this picture will explain things better)

Comment: I supposed that you need to show latitude/longitude in a different positions on screen, right? 0.o

Comment: @FrancisRodrigues yes you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you get now is that map is centered, meaning your provided locations are centered on the map. And you want those locations to be on the upper part of the screen.

It seems [there is not](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory.html#newLatLngBounds(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds,%20int)) such an API, that would allow to apply padding to bottom only.

You can add a fake location to `LatLngBounds.Builder` at the lower part of the screen, now the `CameraUpdate` would include that point also, which will shift your 2 real points on the upper part.

Comment: Yes you understood correctly i will try something like this. Ty

Comment: @MePo I'd suggest you the same doc. I believe that with this doc you can accomplish what you want, just as I also solved this same problem. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the `setPadding` method](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setPadding(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) from the `GoogleMap` object.

In your case you will need to add a bottom padding:

```
mMap.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 150);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late, but i solved this. I make bottom padding for map, before call animateCamera, and return padding after update.

```
val heightValue = (Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.heightPixels * 0.5).toInt()
map.setPadding(0,0,0,heightValue)

 val update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,50)

 map.animateCamera(update,object:GoogleMap.CancelableCallback{
            override fun onFinish() {
                inUi {
                    map.setPadding(0,0,0,0)
                }
            }

            override fun onCancel() {}
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best solution I found to achieve this effect.
You force the padding you need before animating the camera, and immediately after, you reset the padding to whatever ever value.

```kotlin
map.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom) // In your example, this will be the only non-zero value.
animateCamera(cameraUpdate) // Trigger the animation
map.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0) // Reset the padding
```