# fixed marker shifted above camera position google maps flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps-markers, google-maps-flutter

i have an app that have google map with a fixed marker centered on the top half of screen ... i do know how to update marker position according to camera position , **i already tried to shift camera away from marker location by using 256 / math.pow(2, zoom)** it didn't work well with different screen sizes .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl3kj.jpg)
i think my answer is here
[Google map LatLngBounds offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43306928/google-map-latlngbounds-offset)
but am not sure what is the steps to do so